# Refer to child type in parent when child property is an array

Tags: typescript

It's hard to explain, so I made a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATgDRoYDGA9kWADYQAeuqG3UJ2AzsHIBLPAHNq3AL7UpKFAHoFUegGtctTHijkIAMwpRg9IwAtooSCr1QGTVmyh7yjWCj0E8tYMPraA7sLApgDCjCzsMAAUYC5guDAA2gDkdhFsyQC6AJTINOhKULH0YAB0UIUAPAC01VgExmmswNB69ORQySTJUP7tqvxQ5roociiW0ABCCHncOPjEZFT5tuEOnCvcfFCCIuKSGFKJmbLyhXj0wCrqQ-T%20Ria6Bh3GZhbg0PQ2TexOLkRQaZRYRiC57MRvLDkciYEDZAD87k83l8ASCoTW7EmMTiuEmKR%20GRyswwhWKZQqyhqdUwDXoPxag0w0NhTmRPj8-EoUAAkr0tFcuj1XmR6o1MS0ACZDCgQUYoIA).

```
type A = {
    a: number,
    complex: {
        b:string,
    },
}

// ok: can refer to the type of complex from A
function withComplexA(prop: A['complex']) {
    // prop. // <-- autocomplete for 'b' works here
}

type B = {
    a: number,
    complex: {
        b: string,
    }[],
}

// not ok: how to refer to the type of complex from B (ignoring the array)?
function withComplexB(prop: B['complex']) {
    // prop. // <-- autocompletes array functions, I want 'b' to be autocompleted here
}
```

Edit: I accepted an answer below. For completeness, here is another solution I found. ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATgDRoYDGA9kWADYQAeuqG3UJ2AzsHIBLPAHNq3AL7UpKFAHoFUegGtctTHijkIAMwpRg9IwAtooSCr1QGTVmyh7yjWCj0E8tYMPraA7sLApgDCjCzsMAAUYC5guDAA2gDkdhFsyQC6AJTINOhKULH0YAB0UIUAPAC01VgExmmswNB69ORQySTJUP7tqvxQ5roociiW0ABCCHncOPjEZFT5tuEOnCvcfFCCIuKSGFKJmbLyhXj0wCrqQ-T%20Ria6Bh3GZhbg0PQ2TexOLkRQaZRYRiC57MRvLDkciYEDZAD87k83l8ASCoTW7EmMTiuEmKR%20GRyswwhWKZQqyhqdUwDXoPxag0w0NhTmRPj8-EoUAAkr0tFcuj1XmR6o1MS0ACZDCgQUbyCZQEIzLgYeaEUgUA7oQkbHgYba7UQSFZHE7yxTKfj0ZgNVHjD5QADKBDAmAAomwhJhvJUACoAPhmfqg7BaeElgxgLJAlVEzygAFUg-Ck1BcHgIAA3CgAbjOyjUGi0On0hlewXeVi%20q3sv2crhCSK8HLRwTCdbYIRxJVwLrdnu9vpCBMxRIDuVVBWU5PKVVqYvpEta7U63V6-UGwzlciAA))

```
type C = {
    a: number,
    complex: {
        b: string,
    }[],
}

// solution
type SupaExtract<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;

// ok: can refer to the type of complex from C
function withComplexC(prop: SupaExtract<C['complex']>) {
    // prop. // <-- autocomplete for 'b' works here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index into the array with a number:

```
function withComplexB(prop: B['complex'][number]) {
    prop.b // ok
}
```

`B['complex'][0]` and even `B['complex'][48179809412]` would also work but I like to use `number` for clarity/explicitness.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1AMAw)

Comment: Just found this in the handbook (after you posted your answer). (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)